# How Nodejs process.env works

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

I have a ENVIRONMENT Variable , which resolves the current stage inside the container in kubernetes.
when i refer the variable inside code it always prints "dev" even when the actual value refers to "stage". inside container .

my helm variables :

```
profiles:
  - node
owner:
  group: gcp-admin # change to your own group
notify:
  slack:
    channelName: XXXXXXXX-ingestion # change to your own slack channel

build:
  docker:
    app:
      runtime: node
      buildArgs:
        nodeVersion: 14.17.1
        buildDir: '.'
deploy:
  helm:
    values:
      env:
        ENVIRONMENT: stage
```

my java script code goes like this..

```
env: process.env.ENVIRONMENT
```

when i write console.log(env) it always prints dev.
the below image is what i get when i run **describe pod**

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide a [mcve]?  That image file looks like something started a virtual display, ran the Kubernetes `kubectl describe` command, and rendered its results; is that code sequence relevant?  Is this related to Kubernetes, and if so, can you provide a relevant excerpt of the Kubernetes YAML or Helm chart (as text and not an image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your configuration looks old (verify the version). You can refer to the below doc.

```
env:
 - name: ENVIRONMENT
   value: "stage"
```

Read more here:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/
- https://phoenixnap.com/kb/helm-environment-variables

Comment: its still printing DEV @xdeepakv

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar but env name was “APP_ENV” instead and it works

```
  helm:
    values:
      env:
        APP_ENV: "staging" // or "development" or "production"
```

and in code

```
if (process.env.APP_ENV == "staging") {
```